# How to update graphview data in android

Tags: graph, reset, android-graphview

I need to update my graphview data continuously receiving through bluetooth, i am using **com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView** ,I called Bluetooth connection, data communication logics in a Service class to maintain bluetooth connection throughout the Application, From Service class i need to update my Graphview whenever i receive new bluetooth data, Currently my graphview data overlaps with new data, I need to plot 3 graphs(Red,Yellow and blue phase) at a time with 2 series Voltage and Current. I need to reset the whole data each time, please suggest, I tried resetData method but no help, please suggest a solution

```
if(writeMessage.contains("$W11")){      //R Phase

                        String VRMagnitude_red = null,IRMagnitude_red = null, Theta_red = null;
                        int color=0;
                        int thickness=0;

                        list.remove("$W11");
                        if(writeMessage.contains("VR")){
                            list.remove("VR");
                            thickness=3;

                            VRMagnitude_red = (String) list.get(32);
                            System.out.println("--------------VR Magnitude[Red] "+VRMagnitude_red);
                            list.remove(VRMagnitude_red);
                            System.out.println("--------------list size "+list.size());
                        }
                        else if(writeMessage.contains("IR")) {
                            list.remove("IR");
                            thickness=0;

                            IRMagnitude_red = (String) list.get(32);
                            System.out.println("--------------IR Magnitude[Red] "+IRMagnitude_red+", "+list.size());
                            list.remove(IRMagnitude_red);

                            Theta_red = (String) list.get(32);
                            System.out.println("--------------Theta[Red] "+Theta_red);
                            list.remove(Theta_red);
                            System.out.println("--------------list size "+list.size());
                        }
                        color = Color.RED;
                        System.out.println("--------------ArrayList after removing spl chars--  "+list);

                        //---------------SINE WAVEFORM 1 starts--------------------
                        try {
                            dataPoints1 = new DataPoint[list.size()];
                            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                                Double y = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(list.get(i)));
                                dataPoints1[i] = new DataPoint(i, y);
                                System.out.println("--------------ArrayList elements [Red]--  " + list.get(i));
                            }

                            //First scale of Red phase
                            series1 = new LineGraphSeries<>(dataPoints1);
                            //Second Scale of Red phase
                            series2 = new LineGraphSeries<>(dataPoints1);

                            series1.setThickness(thickness);
                            series1.setColor(color);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView1.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView1.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView1.getViewport().setMinX(0);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView1.getViewport().setMaxX(32);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView1.getViewport().setMinY(-1);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView1.getViewport().setMaxY(1);

                            // Set second scale
                            WaveformActivity.graphView1.getSecondScale().addSeries(series2);
                            // The y bounds are always manual for second scale
                            WaveformActivity.graphView1.getSecondScale().setMinY(-1);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView1.getSecondScale().setMaxY(1);
                            series2.setColor(color);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView1.getGridLabelRenderer().setVerticalLabelsSecondScaleColor(color);

                            WaveformActivity.graphView1.addSeries(series1);

                            newRSeries=false;

                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }else if(writeMessage.contains("$W12")){  //Y Phase

                        String VRMagnitude_yellow = null,IRMagnitude_yellow = null, Theta_yellow = null;
                        int color=0;
                        int thickness=0;

                        list.remove("$W12");
                        if(writeMessage.contains("VY")){
                            list.remove("VY");
                            thickness=3;

                            VRMagnitude_yellow = (String) list.get(32);
                            System.out.println("--------------VR Magnitude[Yellow] "+VRMagnitude_yellow);
                            list.remove(VRMagnitude_yellow);
                            System.out.println("--------------list size "+list.size());
                        }
                        else if(writeMessage.contains("IY")) {
                            list.remove("IY");
                            thickness=0;

                            IRMagnitude_yellow = (String) list.get(32);
                            System.out.println("--------------IR Magnitude[Yellow] "+IRMagnitude_yellow+", "+list.size());
                            list.remove(IRMagnitude_yellow);

                            Theta_yellow = (String) list.get(32);
                            System.out.println("--------------Theta[Yellow] "+Theta_yellow);
                            list.remove(Theta_yellow);
                            System.out.println("--------------list size "+list.size());
                        }
                        color = Color.parseColor("#feaa0c");
                        System.out.println("--------------ArrayList after removing spl chars--  "+list);

                        //---------------SINE WAVEFORM 2 starts--------------------

                        dataPoints2 = new DataPoint[list.size()];
                        try {
                            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                                Double y = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(list.get(i)));
                                dataPoints2[i] = new DataPoint(i, y);
                                System.out.println("--------------ArrayList elements [YELLOW]--  " + list.get(i));
                            }

                            series3 = new LineGraphSeries<>(dataPoints2);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView2.addSeries(series3);
                            series3.setThickness(thickness);
                            series3.setColor(color);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView2.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView2.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView2.getViewport().setMinX(0);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView2.getViewport().setMaxX(32);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView2.getViewport().setMinY(-1);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView2.getViewport().setMaxY(1);

                            //Second Scale
                            series4 = new LineGraphSeries<>(dataPoints2);
                            // Set second scale
                            WaveformActivity.graphView2.getSecondScale().addSeries(series4);
                            // The y bounds are always manual for second scale
                            WaveformActivity.graphView2.getSecondScale().setMinY(-1);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView2.getSecondScale().setMaxY(1);
                            series4.setColor(color);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView2.getGridLabelRenderer().setVerticalLabelsSecondScaleColor(color);

                            newYSeries=false;

                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }else if(writeMessage.contains("$W13")){  //B Phase

                        String VRMagnitude_blue = null,IRMagnitude_blue = null, Theta_blue = null;
                        int color=0;
                        int thickness=0;

                        list.remove("$W13");
                        if(writeMessage.contains("VB")){
                            list.remove("VB");
                            thickness=3;

                            VRMagnitude_blue = (String) list.get(32);
                            System.out.println("--------------VR Magnitude[Blue] "+VRMagnitude_blue);
                            list.remove(VRMagnitude_blue);
                            System.out.println("--------------list size "+list.size());
                        }
                        else if(writeMessage.contains("IB")) {
                            list.remove("IB");
                            thickness=0;

                            IRMagnitude_blue = (String) list.get(32);
                            System.out.println("--------------IR Magnitude[Blue] "+IRMagnitude_blue+", "+list.size());
                            list.remove(IRMagnitude_blue);

                            Theta_blue = (String) list.get(32);
                            System.out.println("--------------Theta[Blue] "+Theta_blue);
                            list.remove(Theta_blue);
                            System.out.println("--------------list size "+list.size());
                        }
                        color = Color.BLUE;
                        System.out.println("--------------ArrayList after removing spl chars--  "+list);

                        //---------------SINE WAVEFORM 3 starts--------------------

                        dataPoints3 = new DataPoint[list.size()];
                        try {
                            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                                Double y = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(list.get(i)));
                                dataPoints3[i] = new DataPoint(i, y);
                                System.out.println("--------------ArrayList elements [BLUE]--  " + list.get(i));
                            }

                            series5 = new LineGraphSeries<>(dataPoints3);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView3.addSeries(series5);
                            series5.setThickness(thickness);
                            series5.setColor(color);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView3.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView3.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView3.getViewport().setMinX(0);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView3.getViewport().setMaxX(32);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView3.getViewport().setMinY(-1);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView3.getViewport().setMaxY(1);

                            //Second Scale
                            series6 = new LineGraphSeries<>(dataPoints3);
                            // Set second scale
                            WaveformActivity.graphView3.getSecondScale().addSeries(series6);
                            // The y bounds are always manual for second scale
                            WaveformActivity.graphView3.getSecondScale().setMinY(-1);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView3.getSecondScale().setMaxY(1);
                            series6.setColor(color);
                            WaveformActivity.graphView3.getGridLabelRenderer().setVerticalLabelsSecondScaleColor(color);

                            newBSeries = false;

                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

Also i try to clear old series data with new series data inside ConnectedThread class using below code,

```
public void run() {
    Log.d("DEBUG BT", "IN CONNECTED THREAD RUN");

    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int begin = 0;
    int bytes = 0;
    while (true) {
        try {

            System.out.println("-------------New Series");
            newRSeries = true;
            newYSeries = true;
            newBSeries = true;

            //newWSeries = true;

            al = new ArrayList<>();

            bytes += mmInStream.read(buffer, bytes, buffer.length - bytes);

            if(newRSeries && WaveformActivity.graphView1!=null && dataPoints1!=null){
                WaveformActivity.graphView1.removeAllSeries();
                WaveformActivity.graphView1.getSecondScale().removeAllSeries();
            }
            if(newYSeries && WaveformActivity.graphView2!=null && dataPoints2!=null){
                WaveformActivity.graphView2.removeAllSeries();
                WaveformActivity.graphView2.getSecondScale().removeAllSeries();
            }
            if(newBSeries && WaveformActivity.graphView3!=null && dataPoints3!=null){
                WaveformActivity.graphView3.removeAllSeries();
                WaveformActivity.graphView3.getSecondScale().removeAllSeries();
            }
            if(newRSeries && newYSeries && newBSeries &&
                    WaveformActivity.graphView1!=null && dataPoints1!=null &&
                    WaveformActivity.graphView2!=null && dataPoints2!=null &&
                    WaveformActivity.graphView3!=null && dataPoints3!=null){

                WaveformActivity.graphView1.removeAllSeries();
                WaveformActivity.graphView1.getSecondScale().removeAllSeries();
                WaveformActivity.graphView2.removeAllSeries();
                WaveformActivity.graphView2.getSecondScale().removeAllSeries();
                WaveformActivity.graphView3.removeAllSeries();
                WaveformActivity.graphView3.getSecondScale().removeAllSeries();
            }

            for(int i = begin; i < bytes; i++) {
                if(buffer[i] == "#".getBytes()[0]) {
                    bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(1, begin, i, buffer).sendToTarget();
                    begin = i + 1;
                    if(i == bytes - 1) {
                        bytes = 0;
                        begin = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```